# How to push docker images into a private registry with a full URL?

Tags: docker

My server sits at: `http://localhost:5000/server/api/docker/`

How do I push into that? (And no, I cannot use a reverse proxy to point it to the root):

`docker push localhost:5000/server/api/docker/myimagename`

Furthermore, how does the client knows to connect via HTTPS? Is it by default?

Comment: You must use a reverse proxy as shown at this page http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories (scroll down till you see nginx, apache or haproxy)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible at the moment. But you always can open a feature request on the github repository: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry.